# Java Serialize with Inheritance?

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

Here is the `Goals.java`

```
public abstract class Goals {
private String score;

public Goals(String str) {
    this.score = str;
}

String getGoals() {
    return this.score;
}

   void doSomething(score) {
    }
    }
```

Here is the `Game.java`

```
public class Game implements Serializable {
    public String name;
    public int game_num;
    public int opp;
    public int player;
    public Goals goal;

    public Game(int i, int i2, int i3) {
        this.player = i;
        this.game_num = i2;
        this.opp = i3;
    }

    public Game(String str, Goals goal) {
        this.name = str;
        this.goal = goal;
    }

}
```

Can we create a Serialized Object in a way that after it is deserialized and casted to `Game` , it will set `score` inside `Goals.java` ?
Also, can you manipulate / overwrite `doSomething` method if the serialized data comes from untrusted source?

Comment: Yes, you can do, just make Goals serializable

Answer (score 0):

In the way you are trying to manipulates your objects, I think you can do that Goals implements `Serializable`, and Game implements Goals:

```
public abstract class Goals implements Serializable{
private String score;

public Goals(String str) {
    this.score = str;
}

String getGoals() {
    return this.score;
}

   void doSomething(score) {
    }
    }
```

for Game

```
public class Game extends Goals {
    public String name;
    public int game_num;
    public int opp;
    public int player;

    public Game(int i, int i2, int i3) {
        this.player = i;
        this.game_num = i2;
        this.opp = i3;
    }

    public Game(String str) {
        //create constructor also including the properties of Goals
        Super()...
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, implement Goals and its implementation with Serializable and also implement default constructor in both the classes .

Working piece of code:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;

abstract class Goals implements Serializable{
private String score;


public Goals() {
    this(null);
}

public Goals(String str) {
    this.score = str;
}

String getGoals() {
    return this.score;
}

   void doSomething(int score) {
    }
    }

class Game implements Serializable {
    public String name;
    public int game_num;
    public int opp;
    public int player;
    public Goals goal;

    public Game(int i, int i2, int i3) {
        this.player = i;
        this.game_num = i2;
        this.opp = i3;
    }

    public Game(String str, Goals goal) {
        this.name = str;
        this.goal = goal;
    }

}

class GoalImpl extends Goals implements Serializable{
    public GoalImpl() {
        }
    public GoalImpl(String str) {
        super(str);
    }

}

public class Main{
    public static void main(String...s) {
        Goals goal = new GoalImpl("20");
        Game game = new Game("name",goal);

        try
        {   
            //Saving of object in a file
            FileOutputStream file = new FileOutputStream("gamefile.ser");
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(file);


            // Method for serialization of object
            out.writeObject(game);

            out.close();
            file.close();

            System.out.println("Object has been serialized");

        }

        catch(IOException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("IOException is caught");
        }


        Game object1 = null;

        // Deserialization
        try
        {   
            // Reading the object from a file
            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("gamefile.ser");
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(file);

            // Method for deserialization of object
            object1 = (Game)in.readObject();

            in.close();
            file.close();

            System.out.println("Object has been deserialized ");
            System.out.println("score = " + object1.goal.getGoals());
        }

        catch(IOException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("IOException is caught");
        }

        catch(ClassNotFoundException ex)
        {
            System.out.println("ClassNotFoundException is caught");
        }


    }
}
```

Output:

```
Object has been serialized
Object has been deserialized 
score = 20
```

PS:

1. An advice to make score as integer as otherwise you will not be able to do basic operations like increase score or decrease score using inbuilt operators (+ , - )
2. Always place proper getter setter name like getScore() and setScore int this case.
3. Do try to make constructors in sync, for example in case of Game constructor with player id, game num and opposition is called,  Game name and Goals will never be initialized, better to initialize them with default value or other good option is make another constructor accepting all parameters and then from individual constructos you can call master constructor and pass default values for those which are not passed by the calling method.